# Get image src from props onClick in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-props

I'm grabbing a list of images from an API. Then I am passing this image down to a single img element with props. This helps me generate a list of images I am using for thumbnails.

**EDIT**

The image thumbnails are a preview and on click of one of those image thumbnails I want to add the image in full size to the page.

The problem is I want to be able to click on one of those images and pull out its src value so I can eventually mount that image in a full display container:

My efforts have only logged all the images in the list from the api when I really only want the specific image that has been clicked on.

JSON return data:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

1: {image: {image: image: "https://image1.jpg"}}
2: {image: {image: image: "https://image2.jpg"}}
3: {image: {image: image: "https://image3.jpg"}}
4: {image: {image: image: "https://image4.jpg"}}
etc...
```

App.js:

```
// This import file is shown below
import Image from "./components/Images;"    

const App = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    const getImages = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api_for_the_images${key}`
    );

    const data = await response.json();
        setImages(data.images);
    };

    return(
        <>
          {images.map((image) => (
              <Images image={image.image} />
          ))}
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Images.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";    

const Images = (props) => {

    const [ fullSize, setFullSIze ] = useState()

    const getImage = () => {
     // This return all images in the api list
     console.log(props.image);
 
     // I only want the image clicked on
     setFullSize(props.image);
    
    }        

    return(
        <div className="container">
          <img
            className="api-image"
            src={props.image}
            onClick={getImage}
          ></img>
          <div className="full-size-image">
            // This should be a full size image of the 
            // image that was clicked from the api
            <img src{fullSize}></img>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Images;
```

**EDIT**

React generates this html:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="api-image" src="https://image1.jpg/>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img class="api-image" src="https://image2.jpg/>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img class="api-image" src="https://image3.jpg/>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img class="api-image" src="https://image4.jpg/>
</div>
```

How do I target a specific element when react generates them all the same?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You already have access to the `src` property of the images. Where exactly are you trying to access the `src` of the clicked image? In the App component?

Comment: @Jayce444 I've edited the description and the code to reflect what I want better. The image thumbnails are a preview and on click of one of those image thumbnails I want to add the image in full size to the page.

Comment: Can you get the size of the image when the `getImage()` event is called

Comment: @linchong Currently it only logs only the huge list of src links from the api im not sure how to target the element when react generates the elements all exactly the same

Comment: before you map the images,you can console.log each item,see if the value is what you want to pass

Comment: {images.map((image) => 
  console.log(image)
  return <Images image={image.image} />
)}

Comment: @linchong i would only know what to pass by knowing what the user clicked. The map generates a list of preview images. If the user clicks a preview image I need to know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to know which one is clicked, just pass the value when function called

```
import { useState } from "react";    

const Images = (props) => {

    const [ fullSize, setFullSIze ] = useState()

    const getImage = (image) => {
     console.log(image);
    }        

    return(
        <div className="container">
          <img
            className="api-image"
            src={props.image}
            onClick={() => {getImage(props.image)}}
          ></img>
          <div className="full-size-image">
            <img src{fullSize}></img>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Images;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and when you’re `mapping` them you can pass to them an specific `index`, then you can give them an `id`.
This way you can generate them separately with specific `id`.